# Recuperar datos de tablas SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion para la gestion de turnos de un consultorio medico, cuando registro un nuevo turno guardo el id del mismo (autoincremental) y guardo un id del paciente, uno del medico, y uno del estado del turno.

Pero cuando recupero los datos para mostrarlos en un JTable me da los ids antes dichos, en vez de los nombres como quisiera que los muestre.

¿hay alguna forma de mostrar esos datos, es decir, el nombre del paciente, la descripción del estado?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido. Pon el código de la consulta que utilizas y la estructura de las tablas que estás utilizando.  Por lo que describes ocupas realizar una consulta que relacione las tres tablas. (Paciente, médico y turno). Es algo sencillo pero laborioso. Te recomiendo usar http://sqlfiddle.com/ para mostrar las tablas y hacer los ejemplos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lee este articulo y considera replantear tu pregunta http://www.edu4java.com/es/sql/sql5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, son consultas de tablas relacionadas, no mencionar los nombres ni campos de tus tablas así que les pondré un nombre yo, supongamos tenemos las siguientes tablas:

`Turnos`
con los siguientes campos:
 
`Id_Turno`, `Id_Paciente_T`, `Id_Medico_T`, `Id_Estado_T`

`Pacientes`
con los siguientes campos:
`Id_Paciente`, `Nombre_completo`, `Fecha_Nacimiento`

`Medicos`
 con los siguientes campos:
 `Id_Medico`, `Nombre_Completo`, `Fecha_Nacimiento`

`Estados_Turnos`
con los siguientes campos:
 `Id_Estado_Turno`, `Nombre`, `Descripcion`

Y la consulta seria de la siguiente forma, utilizaré alias para las tablas para que sea más sencillo referenciar las relaciones

```
SELECT P.Nombre_Completo, M.Nombre_Completo, ET.Nombre 
FROM Turnos T, Pacientes P, Medicos M, Estados_Turnos ET
WHERE T.Id_Paciente_T = P.Id_Paciente
AND T.Id_Medico_T = M.Id_Medico
AND T.Id_Estado_T = ET.Id_Estado_Turno
```

Y eso daría como resultado los campos que desearías ver